# Thread Library for Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Anyone know of a good threading library for Java. Only real requirement for it is I need to modify the scheduler. Might have more requirements later so customization would be nice. Any advice or info on your experience with them would be great.

Thanks

Comment: could you be a little more specific with what you are looking for, or the task that you need to accomplish?

Comment: "modify the scheduler"? If you're talking about thread scheduling then you're out of luck: that's outside the scope of all current JVM implementations (older JVMs used green threads and had to do it manually) and is a task taken over by the operating system.

Comment: @Joachim Yea, my end goal is to be able to apply different thread scheduling algorithms depending on the state of the machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `java.util.concurrent` package does not satisfy your requirements, [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) is a great, open source, scheduler which allows you to schedule jobs for repeated execution, along with a whole lot of advanced features like fail-over, load-balancing, etc. I've used it for years and love it, but if `java.util.concurrent` will meet your needs, stick with that.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at `java.util.concurrent` package: [Package introduction documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). It should have everything you need.

Answer (score 4):

I would also suggest you stick with `java.util.concurrent`. You can modify how threads are scheduled for execution to a limited extend by implementing a custom `ExecutorService`.

If you're going to be doing any serious work with the concurrent package, I highly recommend Brian Goetz's book [Java Concurrency in Practice.](http://jcip.net/)